# How can I restrict a Flat Rate to a single product SKU?

Tags: commerce

Shipping 2.0.
Flat Rate is $4.95.
I only want to offer this one Flat Rate I created to product SKU= 146

The place I am confused is in editing Conditions. What do I set the "Data Selector" to? Everything else makes sense to me but the Data Selector.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the context of the event. If that event is receiving an order by default, then your conditions either need to be based on the order (such as "Order contains a particular product") or you'd need to loop over commerce-order:commerce-line-items and evaluate line item based conditions via custom Rules components.

I'd give that condition I mention above a shot before trying anything more complicated, though.